# How do I create a "netlink" between kernel and userspace?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, device-driver, netlink

I want to use netlink to communicate between an application and kernel space. My Linux kernel version is 2.6.28, and the following is my wrong code:

```
nf_sock=netlink_kernel_create(NL_PROTO,0,nl_user_skb,THIS_MODULE);
```

The abbreviated error message is:

```
error: too few arguments to function 'netlink_kernel_create'
```

In the file `<linux/netlink.h>`, the function `netlink_kernel_create()` is defined as

```
extern struct sock *netlink_kernel_create(struct net *net,int unit,unsigned int groups,void (*input)(struct sk_buff *skb),struct mutex *cb_mutex,struct module *module)
```

I don't understand what to use for the first argument, `net`. Can someone explain what I should use here?

Comment: Where did you get the function definition from? Remember the user-space to libc API may not be exactly the libc to kernel syscall API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `struct net` contains information about the network namespace, a set of network resources available to processes. Note that there could be multiple network namespaces (i.e. multiple instances of the networking stack), but most drivers use the init_net namespace.

Your call should probably look something like the following

```
nf_sock = netlink_kernel_create(&init_net,
                                NETLINK_USERSOCK,
                                0,
                                nl_rcv_func,
                                NULL,
                                THIS_MODULE);
```

where `nl_rcv_func` is a function taking `struct sk_buff *skb` as the only argument and processes the received netlink message.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have been following a guide such as [this one](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/7356/print), which (being from 2005) might well have been outpaced by the development of the kernel. It seems the internal API to create a netlink from the kernel side has changed.

Either check the Documentation/ folder in your local kernel tree for some (hopefully fresher) documentation, or read the code itself. You could also [trawl](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/) the Linux Kernel mailing list archives for any mention of the changes that seem to have happened.

[Here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.29/net/netlink/af_netlink.c) is the actual implemntation as of 2.6.29, if you'd rather puzzle it out backwards (and haven't already checked this in your own tree, of course).

Comment: @unwind: Your last link was broken so I changed it.  I pretty confident in my guess, but please check it to make sure I linked to the right page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, struct net is indeed for net namespace, but it is not proper to always use init_net, you should register your own pernet_operations, like this:

```
static struct pernet_operations fib_net_ops = {
        .init = fib_net_init,
        .exit = fib_net_exit,
};

static int __net_init fib_net_init(struct net *net)
{
        int error;

#ifdef CONFIG_IP_ROUTE_CLASSID
        net->ipv4.fib_num_tclassid_users = 0;
#endif
        error = ip_fib_net_init(net);
        if (error < 0)
                goto out;
        error = nl_fib_lookup_init(net);
        if (error < 0)
                goto out_nlfl;
        error = fib_proc_init(net);
        if (error < 0)
                goto out_proc;
out:
        return error;

out_proc:
        nl_fib_lookup_exit(net);
out_nlfl:
        ip_fib_net_exit(net);
        goto out;
}

static int __net_init nl_fib_lookup_init(struct net *net)
{
        struct sock *sk;
        struct netlink_kernel_cfg cfg = {
                .input  = nl_fib_input,
        };

        sk = netlink_kernel_create(net, NETLINK_FIB_LOOKUP, &cfg);
        if (sk == NULL)
                return -EAFNOSUPPORT;
        net->ipv4.fibnl = sk;
        return 0;
}
```

and finally:

```
register_pernet_subsys(&fib_net_ops);
```

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest [ioctl](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ioctl) for kernel/user communication. The ioctl interface is standard and the chance of been updated between kernels is small.

Comment: ioctl's may work for simple changes but the interface is a hoary and brittle one to manage. Netlink is the preferred API of kernel developers for anything moderately complex.